# PJax - how do I turn off the modified behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I've got PJax up and running on my test site - it works a treat. However it relies heavily on a lot of javascript widgets and hence leaks memory.

Since I don't have time right now to re-write every widget, I thought that a simple solution would be to do a normal page load after, say 20 pjax page transitions. A simple plan....but it doesn't seem to be possible.

```
$.pjax.disable();
```

....still fetches the content via AJAX, but doesn't change the page.

```
$(document).pjax();.
```

...doesn't change the behaviour

```
$.pjax.handleClick = function (event, container, options) { return; };
```

...doesn't change the behaviour

```
$.pjax.state.timeout = 0;
```

...doesn't change the behaviour

```
delete $.pjax;
```

...breaks navigation

```
$.pjax.defaults.timeout=0;
```

...doesn't change the behaviour

How do I suspend pjax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a listener for `pjax:beforeSend`, you can capture the requested URL, set `location.href` yourself and `return false` to cancel the pjax behavior. That is how I'm doing it with the following code:

```
var pageLoadCounter = 0;
var MAX_PAGE_LOADS = 20;

$(".pjaxContainer").on("pjax:beforeSend", function (e, xhr, settings) {
    if (++pageLoadCounter > MAX_PAGE_LOADS) {
        // URI can be found at https://github.com/medialize/URI.js
        var uri = URI(settings.url);

        // Remove _pjax from query string before reloading
        uri.removeSearch("_pjax");

        location.href = uri.toString();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that changing the id of the pjax container div gives me the desired result - although this seems like a bit of a kludge. It would also be possible by changing the timeout of the ajax request to 0 - but I still need to work out how to do this.

I did ask on the [PJax github page](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/287) about this but so far have not received a response.